# Get distinct values in array when distinct too big, 16mb cap

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following documents in the products collection:

```
{
   "_id": "1",
   "labels": ["item-1", "item-2"]
},
{
   "_id": "2",
   "labels": ["item-1", "item-4"]
}
```

I am trying to get a list of all distinct values in the "labels" array of each document:

```
item-1
item-2
item-4
```

I am getting the error `"errmsg" : "distinct too big, 16mb cap"` when I run the distinct command:

```
db.products.distinct("labels")
```

I tried running an aggregate function but i'm getting combination of labels and not the list of distinct labels. How can I make the $group return a distinct list of individual labels and not the distinct combination of labels?

```
[
  {
     $group: {
        _id : "$labels"
     }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use unwind and group

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$labels" },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "labels": { "$addToSet": "$labels" }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/C73-Ov7lSzU)**

Comment: Still doesn't work if `labels` is too big and the `$group` stage results in a document bigger than the [maximum BSON size](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-BSON-Document-Size): https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-group:~:text=The%20resulting%20documents%20must%20not%20exceed%20the%20BSON%20Document%20Size%20limit%20of%2016%20megabytes.